# 'Foo' object has no attribute 'myList'

Tags: python

```
class Foo:
   
    def __init__(self, mylist):
    
        self.mylist =mylist
    
    def myIter(self):
        for i in self.myList:
            print(i)
            
first = [1,2,4,3,5,6]
f = Foo(first)
f.myIter()
```

I am trying to pass List as a parameter to the object of the class .

Comment: It's a typo mistake `for i in self.mylist:`

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to always use `snake_case` for functions and variables alike (because remember, in python, functions are variables), and `CamelCase` for classes.

Sticking to that code of conduct will help you avoid this kind of typo (at least it helped me a lot)

In your case, your variable `mylist` is lowercase but your loop is searching for `myList` with uppercase L.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your pointed noted ...